# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.tiles.evaluator.el.ELAttributeEvaluator.setApplicationContext(org.apache.tiles.TilesApplicationContext)'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts2, apache-tiles, spring-framework-beans

We have a project where we are using `tilesConfigurer` to create the pages.

servlet.xml

```
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" >
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

We are using spring-webmvc-3.2.18.Release and org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.Release jars

While updating the Struts to 6.3.0.2,  we are getting this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/esextn-dispatcherservlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.tiles.evaluator.el.ELAttributeEvaluator.setApplicationContext(org.apache.tiles.TilesApplicationContext)'
```

Please help on what libraries to be used here

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots or images of code, try posting the actual code so that it becomes easier for others to analyze.

Comment: Put the code and errors in the text, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Struts 6.3.0 the Tiles project is integrated to Struts 2 tiles plugin. If you have old tiles jar dependencies then it should e removed from the classpath. Because you are using a [**deprecated** API for Tiles 2.2](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/apidocs/deprecated-list.html).

> [Tiles reintroduced into Struts](https://softwaremill.com/how-apache-struts-supports-apache-tiles/)
>
> The history has come full circle, as the Struts team decided to reintegrate the Tiles source code into the [Struts Tiles plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles/). This effort took place in Struts version [6.3.0](https://struts.apache.org/announce-2023#a20230904), and now you can fully enjoy having Tiles up to date and supported.

Comment: But, what about the servlet.xml dependencies for tiles? Is there any suggestions for those?

Comment: It is Spring dependency, there might be conflicts in dependencies.